# Issue with role checking in Symfony authentication success handler

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5.4

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // Get the authenticated user
    $user = $token->getUser();

    // Check the user's role
    if ($user->getRoles() === 'ROLE_ADMIN') { 
        // Redirect to the app_admin page
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_admin'));
    } elseif ($user->getRoles() === 'ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR') { 
        // Redirect to the app_instructeur page
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_instructeur'));
    } else {
        // Redirect to the app_user page
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_user'));
    }
}
```

> I'm working on a Symfony 5.4 application, and I have a custom authentication success handler where I'm checking the user's roles to determine the appropriate redirection. However, I seem to be encountering an issue with the role checking logic.

Comment: Note to self (ignore this):
1: InstructeurController maken 
2: Ifstatement onAuthenticationSuccess updaten (Loginauthenticator)
3: access_control updaten (admin, instructeur en !!leerling!!) 
4: UserController route updaten naar /leerling

Comment: Regel 20 $user = new User();
Regel 31 $user ->setRoles(["ROLE_LEERLING"]);

Comment: *: Routes updaten navbar + Unieke paginas en routes (/leerling/home)
!Footer algemene voorwaarden alleen bij bezoeker!
!Comments weghalen!

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" alt="...">

Comment: I don't get it.  You deleted a previous question and then reposted part of it?  Added a few `stream of consciousness comments` and then accepted something from the previous question? Plenty of folks try to bump their questions even though it is not necessary but this one just seems bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used strict equality (===) to compare the user's roles with the strings 'ROLE_ADMIN' and 'ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR'.
However, the getRoles() method typically returns an array of roles, not a single string.

To fix this mistake, you should use the in_array function:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // Get the authenticated user
    $user = $token->getUser();

    // Check the user's role
    if (in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())) {
        // Redirect to the app_admin page
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_admin'));
    } elseif (in_array('ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR', $user->getRoles())) {
        // Redirect to the app_instructeur page
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_instructeur'));
    } else {
        // Redirect to the app_user page
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_user'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate i've found an easier way to implement this :)
This will aslso help you you could put this in any controller and it will help you out :)

```
 /**
 * @Route("/redirect", name="redirect")
 */
public function redirectAction(Security $security)
{
    if ($security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin');
    }
    if ($security->isGranted('ROLE_EMPLOYEE')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_employee');
    }
    if ($security->isGranted('ROLE_MEMBER')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_member');
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_guest');
}
```

you can add the 2nd text inside your securityAuthenticator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).